# Why can I execute a statically linked riscv helloworld program on my Intel i5? I am running Debian testing

Tags: riscv

Why does that even work on my Intel i5? Why can I execute it natively?

```
# riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc-7 hello.c -o hello -static
# ./hello 
Hello World!
# file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, UCB RISC-V, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 4.15.0, BuildID[sha1]=519dabc53e2d6cccc48750975ee60000263d0c95, not stripped
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc).
IOW, there's an emulator registered in the system that runs programs compiled for other architectures.